# Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of null

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I have problem with my code. I am trying to do simple scroll function, but i still received an error.

```
    <script>
    function pageScroll(el) {
    var yPos;
    page = document.getElementById(el);
    var height = page.offsetTop;

    window.scroll(0, height);
    }
</script>

<button class="module-box" onclick="pageScroll(about)">READ</button>
```

Comment: This means `page` doesn't store what you think it does.

Comment: Try sending the argument as a string - instead of `pageScroll(about)` try using `pageScroll('about')`. This should do the trick.

Comment: I suppose that the problem lies in the variable page, but you can explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @LeoNapoleon THANKS!

Comment: about should be a string to be able call getElementById so replace pageScroll(about) with pageScroll('about')

Answer (score 2):

Working code.
Need to pass id as string to the function.

```js
function showTop(el)
{
  var page = document.getElementById(el);
    var height = page.offsetTop;
  alert(height);
  }
```

```html
<div id="new"></div>
<button onclick = "showTop('new')">Click me</button>
  <div id='op'></div>
```